# Bug in awarding Enlightened Badge

Tags: support, bug, status-norepro, badges, enlightened-badge

I have found doubt full awarding of Enlightened Badge

Look at here : https://stackoverflow.com/badges/19/enlightened?userid=907729

This badge was awarded on [Different ways to accomplish chat on IPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190025/different-ways-to-accomplish-chat-on-iphone/7191923#7191923)

as per the description of Enlightened badge..

```
First to answer and accepted with score of 10 or more. This badge can be awarded multiple times.
```

But on that question, answer have only 1 upvote an not accepted but badge was awarded. BUG!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is fine, actually the user has a previous answer which has 10 upvotes, that was later deleted by a moderator.

See the image of that deleted answer.

> [image]

Comment: same user : http://stackoverflow.com/users/907729/crime-master-gogo

Comment: @SumitBijvani, check my updated answer

Comment: but it was not accepted in image!!

Comment: @SumitBijvani, probably it was accepted answer. Once an accepted question gets deleted it doesnt show the acceptance tick mark.

Comment: As an aside, @Sumit and all, the original answer was just a bare link to GitHub, basically the 3rd item from the current answer. I guess that was the reason it was deleted. The deleted version you see above was edited *after* that link-only answer was deleted. 20 minutes later the same was posted as a new answer.

Answer (score 2):

Not a bug. Probably there was an accepted answer which is now removed. Someone with 10K+ reputation can confirm this.

Comment: same user : http://stackoverflow.com/users/907729/crime-master-gogo

Comment: @SumitBijvani - We can add multiple answers.

Comment: ohh, so previous one was deleted?

Comment: You are also close to 10k. :)