# What is the process of awarding 'Enlightened' badge?

Tags: discussion, support, badges

[Enlightened](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/19/enlightened) badge is awarded for [first to answer and accepted with score of 10 or more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21410/186599).

I am confused on seeing some users' answers with this qualification didn't get awarded this badge.

For ex, See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15661867/756941) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15881119/756941) answers, they deserves the Enlightened badge, but they didn't received yet. There may be any valid reason behind that like [Bug in awarding Enlightened Badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/174275/186599). What's that?

Comment: No i can not see any deleted answer there

Comment: also my answer still didn't get Enlightened badge : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196587/get-last-sunday-date-in-php/15196691#15196691  why?

Comment: @Sumit: [Renku answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15196685/214149) 22 seconds before you did - you didn't answer first.

Comment: @Mac I don't see the exact time. it shows `Mar 4 at 7:37` on both answers

Comment: @SumitBijvani - Are you kidding with us? At lease read the comment reply given to you.

Comment: @hims056 no bro, I am not

Comment: @SumitBijvani - Then why are you just asking everyone without reading any reply?

Comment: @hims056 i have read all the comments then I have replied. because I don't see the second difference. my screen display only `Mar 4 at 7:37` on both answer. that's why I am asking how can I see the seconds difference

Comment: But I wanted a [resistance](http://www.gatto999.it/images/stories/Divertimento/Ingress%20resistance%201.png) badge!

Comment: @SumitBijvani - Still you are ignoring [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176871/what-is-the-process-of-awarding-enlightened-badge#comment-531316) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176871/what-is-the-process-of-awarding-enlightened-badge#comment-531320) comments. You actually need to hover on that timestamps to get **exact** time of the post.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The description of the badge is (emphasis mine):

> Enlightened badge is awarded for **first to answer** and accepted with score of 10 or more.

Neither of your answers was the *first* to appear. In the first question you were 26 days late, and in the second one you were a minute late.

Comment: That was really an eagle eye answer :)

Comment: @Azik Because they are both the accepted answer.

Comment: This answer deserves **Enlightened badge**, come on guys

Comment: my answer still didn't get Enlightened badge : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15196587/get-last-sunday-date-in-php/15196691#15196691  why?

Comment: @SumitBijvani Because it's _not_ the first answer, you were 22 seconds too late. Hover over the answers' timestamps to see the _exact_ time they were posted.

Comment: @SumitBijvani Many users who play FGITW get denied the badge by mere seconds. I think I have one answer where I missed it by like 2 seconds.

Comment: @Yannis how can you see. I am 22 seconds late. please tell me. because there are 2 answers at the same time

Comment: @SumitBijvani - Read [Yannis' comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176871/what-is-the-process-of-awarding-enlightened-badge#comment-531316) carefully.

Answer (score 1):

In both of your examples, the accepted answer was not the *first* answer.

Take a closer look at the time-stamps.

- `Mar 27 at 14:49` (accepted) vs `Mar 1 at 15:06`
- `Apr 8 at 14:00` (accepted) vs `Apr 8 at 13:59`